# How to run php code inside a template for node.js

Tags: php, node.js

There is some code to establish a node.js server with a html engine:

```
const express = require('express');
const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');
var cons = require('consolidate');
var path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.engine('html', cons.swig)
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index.html'));
```

However in my index.html file I wanna output some PHP variables. Let's say these look as follows:

```
<p class="places">
    <?php echo $request['places_count'].' places are left now'; ?>
</p>
```

Is that even possible to show php veriables inside node.js and if not, what's the best way to solve the issue?

Comment: The best way to solve this is to use JS to print the values, not PHP.

Comment: what is the end result that you want to achieve?

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar wanna execute php code inside the node.js app

Comment: No, nothing that I know of. To run PHP code one would need a PHP interpreter. Any specific reason you want to do that?